# Aggregate values by levels of another factor but keep all rows in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R with this structure:

```
df1<-data.frame(SiteID=c("A","A","A","B","B","C"),Unrelated=c("dog","cat","catamount","bird","horse","monkey"),AirMonitor=c(1,0,0,0,0,1),WaterMonitor=c(0,1,0,1,0,0),SoilMonitor=c(0,0,1,0,1,0))
```

with output like this:

```
  SiteID Unrelated AirMonitor WaterMonitor SoilMonitor
1      A       dog          1            0           0
2      A       cat          0            1           0
3      A catamount          0            0           1
4      B      bird          0            1           0
5      B     horse          0            0           1
6      C    monkey          1            0           0
```

`1` indicates the presence of that type of monitor at that site (I could change the monitor columns to factors with `"Y"` and `"N"` values instead if needed). Basically, I want to aggregate monitor presence by `SiteID` but then keep all the rows in order not to lose the data in the `Unrelated` column. I want `1` values to win over `0` values. For example, if any row with `SiteID` A has a `1` for `AirMonitor`, I want all rows with `SiteID` A to have a `1` for `AirMonitor`. Same for the other two monitor types.

Desired output:

```
  SiteID Unrelated AirMonitor WaterMonitor SoilMonitor
1      A       dog          1            1           1
2      A       cat          1            1           1
3      A catamount          1            1           1
4      B      bird          0            1           1
5      B     horse          0            1           1
6      C    monkey          1            0           0
```

The real dataset has several more unrelated columns and thousands of rows.  There must be some simple way to do this (maybe with `aggregate`?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, if you want to `aggregate` and keep the rows intact, `ave` can help. So, we use `lapply` to loop through the columns (except the first two) and use `ave` to calculate max value by `SiteID`

```
df1[,-c(1:2)] = lapply(df1[,-c(1:2)], function(a) ave(a, df1$SiteID, FUN = max))
df1
#  SiteID Unrelated AirMonitor WaterMonitor SoilMonitor
#1      A       dog          1            1           1
#2      A       cat          1            1           1
#3      A catamount          1            1           1
#4      B      bird          0            1           1
#5      B     horse          0            1           1
#6      C    monkey          1            0           0
```

Comment: Thank you!  I replaced `-c(1:2)` wherever it occurred with `c("AirMonitor","WaterMonitor","SoilMonitor")` because I had a lot of unrelated columns to preserve, and it still worked.

Comment: I'd probably use `lapply` just to avoid the simplification-to-matrix process that `sapply` does.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df1 %>% group_by(SiteID) %>% mutate_at(vars(-Unrelated), funs(max)) 
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: SiteID [3]

  SiteID Unrelated AirMonitor WaterMonitor SoilMonitor
  <fctr>    <fctr>      <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1      A       dog          1            1           1
2      A       cat          1            1           1
3      A catamount          1            1           1
4      B      bird          0            1           1
5      B     horse          0            1           1
6      C    monkey          1            0           0
```

Alternatively, if you have multiple variables like `Unrelated` and don't want to specify them all the time, you could think of something like

```
df %>% group_by(SiteID) %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(max))
```

This applies `max` to each numeric column on a per-group basis.